# When is a Service started with startService() stopped?

Tags: android, service, media-player

I'm doing a radio app, with a `MediaPlayer` in a `Service`.

I start it with `startService()` when a `StreamPlayerFragment` is created because the audio stream must play as long as the app runs, and I bind it only in `StreamPlayerFragment`, because only this `Fragment` need to access the `MediaPlayer` to play/pause/stop the audio stream.

Now I'm not sure when/how the `Service` should be stopped? I need to know when it's stopped or destroyed to be able to release the `MediaPlayer`.

Should I leave Android kill the `Service` and release the `MediaPlayer` in the `Service`'s `onDestroy`? I can't see other options because I need it to run as long as the app runs...

```
public class StreamPlayerFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // start service

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), StreamService.class);
        getActivity().startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {    

        super.onResume();

        // bind service

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), StreamService.class);
        getActivity().bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        // unbind service

        if (mBound) {
        getActivity().unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
        }

        super.onPause();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start it with `startService()` you will have to stop it with `stopService()`. Unbinding is not enough.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

> If someone calls Context.startService() then the system will retrieve the service (creating it and calling its onCreate() method if needed) and then call its onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method with the arguments supplied by the client. The service will at this point continue running until Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called.

If it needs to run alongside your activity why don't you start it as a bound service?

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: I need it to run alongside the app, not an activity (but it must be bound to the `StreamPlayerFragment`'s `Activity` to control `MediaPlayer` in the `StreamService`). If I want to start it as a bound service, I must bind it to all my activities, which requires lots of useless code and is not needed. I don't want to call `stopService()`, because I want the `Service` to run as long as my app runs. That's why I guess the best way is to leave Android kill the `Service` and release the `MediaPlayer` in the `StreamService`'s `onDestroy()`. I was just wondering if there are other ways...